# jquery modal() closes itself

Tags: jquery, visual-studio

I've an modal in jquery 2.* and running a project in visual studio express for web. When I'm in debug mode and let the page be idle with the modal up, it closes itself after a (long) while. I really can't understand why and having a hard time to figure it out. Does anyone have any idea?

I've looked through the jquery code for setTimeout, but only found 3 calls to setTimeout, none of which I suspect. I also know that visual studio is doing some polling for some reason, that's my main suspect right now, but I can't understand why that would close my modal.

Comment: Your suspicion is probably right. If there is a poll/refresh of the page the dialog will close.

Comment: but why would visual studio do that? It makes it impossible to properly test certain things.

Answer (score 0):

ExecutionTimeOut came to my mind...

```
<location path="THE PAGE YOU NEED TO WATCH">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1000"/> // IN SECONDS
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Here is an answer that covers that topic.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10650168/335905

Update:
From msdn:

> The ExecutionTimeout property indicates the maximum number of seconds
>   a request is allowed to execute before being automatically shut down
>   by ASP.NET. The default is 110 seconds. This time-out applies only if
>   the debug attribute in the  element is set to false.