# How to Set executionTimeout to infinite

Tags: c#, .net, web-config

How to Set **executionTimeout** to infinite.

Some time data on page is big new server takes time .Want to make flexible so that never get error after delay .
Error :The wait  Operation Time out

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649843/how-to-give-maximum-executiontimeout-to-the-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can give it as below in web.config file :-

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout = "10000000000000"/> ////Value is in Second
```

As documented in [official site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  under `executionTimeout` section:-

> This time-out applies only if the debug attribute in the compilation
>   element is False. Therefore, if the debug attribute is True, you do
>   not have to set this attribute to a large value in order to avoid
>   application shutdown while you are debugging. The default is 110
>   seconds

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not advised, you can use '0' for infinity:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout = "0"/>
```