# Asp.Net website dropping connection to download with "Unknown Network Error"

Tags: asp.net, iis, networking, download

I have a website which hands a file to a user via a link. This file is then streamed to the user. The problem I am having is that with larger files the download stops and gets an "Unknown Network Error". Sometimes i get this error at 100mb sometimes at 400mbs. The application used to work fine so I don't believe its the code.

I have looked into the issue and used wireshark on the server. As soon as the file stops i get a group of red packets. I'm not great with wireshark so cant get any useful information for resolving this issue from this?

I am wondering if anyone can point me in a direction to understanding the problem and how to resolve this?

The application is running on IIS 8.

[image: Wireshark output]

Check max execution time in asp.net app in web.config - link, that might be restricting the time to execute this request. –  Arindam Nayak 2 days ago

This fixed the problem

Comment: Check max execution time in asp.net app in web.config - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649843/how-to-give-maximum-executiontimeout-to-the-application), that might be restricting the time to execute this request.

Answer (score 1):

Check max execution time in asp.net app in web.config - link, that might be restricting the time to execute this request. –  Arindam Nayak