# Command Timeout not working

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework to communicate with SQL Server. I set connection timeout = 36000 in connection string, then set command Timeout = 36000 for EF context object. I also set this line in web config.

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="36000" />
```

I also set timeout = 28800 like this.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/view/login/Login.aspx" timeout="28800" defaultUrl="~/view/login/WellComePage.aspx"/>
        </authentication>
```

After setting this all, i fetch data from db. It works fine for small data, but for long queries i got following message after 44 seconds. Although i didn't set 44 anywhere.

> 'Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to
>   completion of the operation or the server is not responding.'

Any idea what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: check out this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649843/how-to-increase-executiontimeout-for-a-long-running-query

Comment: Did you have tried to increase the timeout to for example 2 mintues, just to insure that the Connection does not need more time, otherwise your can you go into debug to see where exactly the code is stuck.

Comment: @TheGameiswar Already checked that link, not worked for me.

Comment: @Bassam Alugili I set both connection and command timeout to 36000. But this didn't impact on execution timeout error.

Comment: where did you do that? in the Connection string you cannot set the command timeout?! you must do that somewhere in the code?

Comment: Yes, i set command timeout in code.