# Where to set HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout in controller?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, connection-timeout

Where to set request timeout on certain ASP.NET controller that has this timeout value?  Is it in the constructor of the controller or somewhere else?

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since ScriptTimeout is an application-wide static setting, the only sensible place to set it would be at application startup.

Alternatively, you could set it in the `web.config` file.

```
<configuration>
...

<system.web>
   <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" />
```

Reference: http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-FAQ/Change-Script-Timeout.aspx

Comment: Bear in mind that the value of executionTimeout is in seconds, and will only have an effect if the "debug" attribute of the tag <compilation> (under <system.web>) is set to "false", as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10650168/2287555). [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-2.0/e1f13641(v=vs.80)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: This is not correct. Setting `ScriptTimeout` only has an effect for the current request. E.g. also mentioned in comment ScriptTimeout https://stackoverflow.com/a/579599/1059776

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the timeout to all actions of the controller setting `ScriptTimeout` seems like a good choice.

One exception would be if the upload duration may already exceed the application-wide `executionTimeout` setting. In that case the timeout occurs before execution reaches the controller and therefore the constructor won't have a chance to make the setting.

A workaround in this scenario is setting `ScriptTimeout` in `Application_BeginRequest` after analyzing `HttpContext.Current.Request.Path`.